# passing object to from view to object in grails

Tags: grails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grails populating a domain instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358212/grails-populating-a-domain-instance)

I am wanting to pass a childInstance object from my view to the controller at the moment I am doing this

```
<g:formRemote url="[action: 'updateStatus']" update="messages" name="updateStatusForm" onSuccess="document.updateStatusForm.message.value='';">
```

the updateStatus method is as follows

```
def updateStatus(String message) {
        def status = new Post(message: params.message, author: lookupPerson())
        System.out.println("status: " + status.message + " : " + status.author)
        status.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
        def messages = currentUserTimeline()
        render template: 'profileMessages', collection: messages, var: 'profileMessage'
    }
```

I want to add a childInstance from my view to the updateStatus. But I also want to to work if I don't pass the childInstance to the update Status.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the url

```
url="[action: 'updateStatus' params:[id:'obj.id']]"
```

and call it in your controller method with

```
object = Obj.get(params.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass object instance as request parameter to the controller. Request parameters are strings. So, you can pass something like object ID as a parameter and then load this object by ID in the controller.

Comment: so if i add params="obj.id" this should work?

Comment: You can add hidden field to your remote form like **<g:hiddenField name="id" value="12345"/>** and load the object in the controller: **DomainObject.get(params.id)**