# Grails populating a domain instance

Tags: grails

I have been stuck for a couple of days on the same problem and I am not getting anywhere.

I am using a g:formRemote tag to update a messages template

```
<g:formRemote url="[action: 'updateStatus']" update="messages" name="updateStatusForm"
                    onSuccess="document.updateStatusForm.message.value='';">
                    <g:textArea name="message" value="" cols="3" rows="1"/><br/>
                    <g:submitButton name="Update Status"/>
                </g:formRemote>
```

This form then calls a updateStatus method in my controller

```
def updateStatus(String message) {
        def status = new Post(message: params.message, author: lookupPerson())
        status.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
        def messages = currentUserTimeline()
        render template: 'profileMessages', collection: messages, var: 'profileMessage'
    }
```

But the def status line should be

```
def status = new Post(message: params.message, author: lookupPerson(), child: Child.get(childInstance.id)
```

In my view I have a childInstance which is the selected by the user. Is there anyway I can have a global variable in the controller which is saved or can I send the child instance params id in the formRemote tag. I don't think there is as i've been trying to do it this way all today.

Any help will be good. The only way I know will work will be to write the childInstance.id to a properties file and read it back in but there must be a better way as I think this would be very bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add params to `<g:formRemote>`

Example from the grails docs:

```
<g:formRemote name="myForm" update="updateMe"
              url="[controller: 'book', action: 'byAuthor', params: [sort: 'title', order: 'desc']]">
    Author: <input name="author" type="text" />
</g:formRemote>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably add a `<g:hiddenField name="childId" value="${childInstance.id}"/>` to your formRemote Tag and this will send it to the server in the same way message is.